# Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed with Ajax

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

i need read a csv file from external server with Ajax Request. Laravel show me this error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/CSVServer/csv/sales.csv' from origin 'http://dashboard.local' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I read many and many articles about CORS, but this doesn't work for me.

my ajax code is:

```
$.get("http://localhost/CSVServer/csv/sales.csv", getDataPointsFromCSV);

function getDataPointsFromCSV(csv) {
    var csvLines = points = [];
    csvLines = csv.split(/[\r?\n|\r|\n]+/);
    for (var i = 0; i < csvLines.length; i++) {
        if (csvLines[i].length > 0) {
            points = csvLines[i].split(",");
            dataPoints.push({
                label: points[0],
                y: parseFloat(points[1])
            });
        }
    }
    chart.render();
}
```

Comment: You need to enable cors on the external server.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/CSVServer/csv/sales.csv",
    headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}
});
```

This is a get request using the Allow-Origin header to avoid the CORS issue.

And since i see your file is a csv maybe you are going to need:

```
Accept: text/csv
```